# Elasticsearch query string query with not equal to?

Tags: elasticsearch

Usually with a query_string query in elasticsearch, I can do:

```
name:"Fred"
```

I want to find all documents where name is not equal to Fred. What is the proper syntax for that? I tried:

```
name!="Fred"
```

Though it returns 0 documents.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You need to use the [NOT operator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boolean_operators), like this:

```
!(name:"Fred")
```

or

```
NOT (name:"Fred")
```

Comment: For those wondering how to concat multiple values `NOT(key:value1 value2 value3)`

Comment: @val can you help here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66331236/making-filter-query-with-elastic-search

Answer (score 87):

You should use bool query with must_not statement

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must_not" : {
        "term" : {
          "name" : "Fred"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why? Which is the better option, to use Query String query or your option?

Comment: @RodriKing there is not better option it depends what you are going to do. In current question question was how to filer on specific term this is why I would use term, query_string on other hand will split your search text to multiple terms. So basically it depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Ok thank you, another little question, please. I want to make a wildcard query, but wildcard queries do not apply to analized/filters (match query does). I want to apply the analysis of ignoring the accents of the words. As with wildcard queries I can't, I'm using query string queries. Would that be correct?

Comment: @RodriKing create separate question with example pls.

Answer (score 31):

You can also use a combination of must and must_not.  Like pull docs where name is Ajit and status is not queued.

```json
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": "Ajit"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "status": "queued"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**and, or and not filters**

---

***For "and" query:***

```json
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "term" : { "name.first" : "shay" }
        },
        "filter" : {
            "and" : {
                "filters" : [
                    {
                        "term" : { "name.first" : "something" }
                    },
                    {
                        "term" : { "name.first" : "other" }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

***For "or" query:***

```json
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "term" : { "name.first" : "shay" }
        },
        "filter" : {
            "or" : {
                "filters" : [
                    {
                        "term" : { "name.first" : "something" }
                    },
                    {
                        "term" : { "name.first" : "other" }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

***For "not" query:***

```json
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "term" : { "name.first" : "shay" }
        },
        "filter" : {
            "not" : {
                "filter" :  {
                    "term" : { "name.first" : "someting" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```